# Why can I not read an ArrayList from ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I am reading and writing an object to disk.  Why does the "save" method work, but when I try the "load" method, the system hangs?  I have kept my reading/writing bytes consistent.

The output of the "System.out.println" method in the "load" method is: 415301485 instead of 3.

Everything works fine if I remove the saving and loading from array.

I am at my wit's end, and almost tempted to give up and try something else.  Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name = "test";
    private int number = 99;
    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private ArrayList<BufferedImage> imageArray = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    public MyClass() {
        try {
        // Load single image
        this.image = ImageIO.read(FileIO.class.getResource("/assets/logo.png"));

        // Add a bunch of images to the array
        imageArray.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/test/1.png")));
        imageArray.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/test/2.png")));
        imageArray.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/test/3.png")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void save(String filename) {


    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

        // Default objects
        oos.writeObject(name);
        oos.writeInt(number);

        // Single image
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", oos);

        // Number of images in array
        oos.writeInt(imageArray.size());

        // Each image
        for (BufferedImage image: imageArray){
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", oos);
        }

        oos.close();
        fout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void load(String filename) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

        // Default objects
        this.name = (String) ois.readObject();
        this.number = ois.readInt();

        // Single image
        this.image = ImageIO.read(ois);

        // Array of images
        int imageCount = ois.readInt();
        System.out.println(imageCount);
        for (int i=0; i<imageCount; i++){
            this.imageArray.add(ImageIO.read(ois));
        }

        ois.close();
        fin.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything but if any exception will be thrown your streams will not invoke `close` methods. That is why it is better to invoke closing methods from `finally` block, or wrap your resources with *try-with-resources*.

Comment: ImageIO.write returns a boolean.  False is returned if no writer could be found.  Check this and tell us what you find out.

Comment: And similarly `ImageIO.read()` can return null. Check it.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I found out...  When saving, ImageIO.write returns TRUE.  The actual problem is `imageCount = ois.readInt()` does not return it originally writes to it.  Right before the write statement, `imageCount = 3`.  Immediately after the read statement, `imageCount=415301485`.  I don't think I fully understand how BufferedImages get encoded in the file.  For instance, is it possible that I have to define the length of the binary file, and read that as a stream of byte arrays instead?  Does that make sense?  Does any of this make sense?  Are we alone in the universe?

Comment: Also, the first image reads fine, but the second one doesn't?  This doesn't make sense to me...